# Creating empty (schema only) Dacpac

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, ssms, dacpac

I need to create an empty schema, with no objects

Original Dacpac:

[image: Original dacpac]

My desired schema, with no tables

[image: Ideal dacpac]

And the target (failed) schema, (once has been imported)

[image: Final dactac showing as empty]

Is there even a way to do this? Or do dacpacs by default **have** to be filled with something in each schemas?

Funny thing is that when you analyze it[image: diff of the both dacpac] it is indeed the same

Perhaps is just a Visual Studio thing? (I haven't actually test it with any other tool, eg, SSMS. If so, any workaround to show the empty schemas?

Comment: `Perhaps is just a Visual Studio thing?` - yes, it is. That tree does not exist on the server.

Comment: And there is no way to modify that right?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you need `CREATE SCHEMA ...` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to open a SQL window within VS or open SSMS so you can use T-SQL.
CREATE SCHEMA Sales;
GO

CREATE TABLE Sales.Region
(Region_id INT NOT NULL,
Region_Name CHAR(5) NOT NULL)
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE);
GO

Notice that the creation of the schema and the creation of the table are separate commands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

To confirm it exists query
select s.name from sys.schemas s